# Why the results on the same val set are different in Model.fit() and Model.evaluate()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to use a resnet50 for a regression task. And I use a custom loss for training. I want to use checkpoints to save the best model which has the minimum loss on testing data. The codes for model's training are as follows:

```
input_shape = (32, 32, 1)
inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

outputs = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=input_shape, pooling='max'
)(inputs)

outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(outputs)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=EWC_loss(model,fisher_1,prior_weights_1,Lambda=1),
              metrics='mse')

checkpoint_filepath_3 = 'F:/NTU_PyCode/CL_regression_mnist/saved_resnet/resnet50_task2_epoch=5(1).h5'

model_checkpoint_callback_2 = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath_3,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    save_best_only=True)

model.fit(x_train_2,y_train_2,batch_size=32,shuffle=True,
          validation_data=(x_test_2, y_test_2), epochs=5,
          callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback_2])
```

And here are the training results. In my plan, the model's weights after the 3rd epoch will be saved to the checkpoint_filepath. Because it has the minimum val_loss (val_mse is not minimum because the custom loss involves other terms).

```
   2/1875 [..............................] - ETA: 1:07 - loss: 8.4497 - mse: 8.4489WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0239s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0449s). Check your callbacks.
1875/1875 [==============================] - 136s 73ms/step - loss: 2.6100 - mse: 2.5062 - val_loss: 5.5797 - val_mse: 5.4108
Epoch 2/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 129s 69ms/step - loss: 1.2896 - mse: 1.1265 - val_loss: 1.6604 - val_mse: 1.4745
Epoch 3/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 128s 68ms/step - loss: 0.9861 - mse: 0.7998 - val_loss: 1.4171 - val_mse: 1.2161
Epoch 4/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 128s 68ms/step - loss: 1.1695 - mse: 0.8958 - val_loss: 1.4705 - val_mse: 1.2034
Epoch 5/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 129s 69ms/step - loss: 1.0095 - mse: 0.7305 - val_loss: 11.7203 - val_mse: 11.4236
```

But when I load the weights and use the evaluate function to evaluate on the same testing data, there comes the problem. The loss is not custom loss here but the metric is still mse. So I assume the mse in evaluation function should be the same to the result in fit function(same as val_mse in the 3rd epoch). But the MSEs are very different!

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.mse,
                metrics='mse')

print("EWC model on Task 2")
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath_3)
model.evaluate(x_test_2,y_test_2)
```

```
EWC model on Task 2
313/313 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 9.1384 - mse: 9.1384
```

What causes this phenomenon? Is that the weights not be saved into the checkpoints? Or any other issues? Thank you in advance~

---

After more experiments, I found a puzzled phenomenon. If I run the codes of training and evaluation together, the results are correct! The results for 2 epochs in training and evaluation are showed as follows. And we can see the MSEs are the same.

```
   2/1875 [..............................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 15.2813 - mse: 15.2805WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0190s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0439s). Check your callbacks.
1875/1875 [==============================] - 137s 73ms/step - loss: 2.0093 - mse: 1.9253 - val_loss: 1.8885 - val_mse: 1.7217
Epoch 2/2
1875/1875 [==============================] - 129s 69ms/step - loss: 1.1946 - mse: 1.0230 - val_loss: 1.1102 - val_mse: 0.9254
EWC model on Task 2
313/313 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 0.9254 - mse: 0.9254
```

But if I train and evaluate separately (run codes for training first, then just load the saved weights in model and evaluate), The results are different.

```
EWC model on Task 2
313/313 [==============================] - 4s 14ms/step - loss: 9.0702 - mse: 9.0702
```

Why is that? That's really confusing. Is there any difference between train and evaluate in one run and separately?

Comment: Have you tested with `shuffle = False `. Your weights might change when you shuffle during training.

Comment: No, I have not. You mean set ```shuffle = False```  in fit()?  In my view, this just affects whether shuffle the training data. Weights may change but will this makes the results in fit() and evaluate() are different? Because these 2 functions may make the model use the same weights if I load them correctly.

Comment: Hi @Ashish. I just tried to run fit() with ```shuffle=False```. It still has the same problem. MSEs are different in fit() and evaluate().

Comment: @GerryP Oh! If I train the model with fit() and then evaluate without recompiling the model, the result is correct.  But if I do these 2 steps separately, i.e. train the model, then recompile it and load the saved weights, then evaluate, the results are different. Why is that?

Comment: I am trying to figure that out as well. Haven't found the answer as yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the details but when you use model checkpoint and save the weights only or even the whole model when you execute model.load_weights it is a complex process that is described [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics) When you recompile before loading the weights that restoration process apparently gets messed up. I did find a note that says changing model.compile can cause the restoration to fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Gerry. But I tried again and I found that even I recompile the model, the results are also correct if I run codes of train and evaluate together. The only factor that affects the results is whether train and evaluate in the same run. I show this issue in my updated part in the question.